# Why does setting --package-path to a local directory give python not found error in gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to run  a gcloud job locally. I try:

```
! gcloud ai-platform local train \
  --package-path trainer \
  --module-name trainer.task \
  --job-dir local-training-output
```

which works fine, but seems to be using the trainer directory under Colab's /content folder.
I want to use the one on my local machine, so I try:

```
! gcloud config set ml_engine/local_python $(which python3)

! gcloud ai-platform local train \
  --package-path /path/to/local/trainer \
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ I have added a path here
  --module-name trainer.task \
```

which gives:

```
Updated property [ml_engine/local_python].
ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.local.train) /usr/bin/python3: command not found
  --job-dir local-training-output
```

I am thinking this might be something to do with gcp and local environments differing but do not know how to check this.

EDIT:
This is local machine

```
which python3
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/gcp/bin/python3
```

EDIT2:

Ah!
this is in google cloud:

```
!which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

EDIT3:
On my local machine:

```
    /usr/bin$ ls -alh python3*

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Apr 15  2019 python3 -> python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Oct 25  2018 python3-config -> python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.4M Nov  7 10:44 python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Nov  7 10:44 python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.4M Nov  7 10:44 python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Nov  7 10:44 python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Apr 15  2019 python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   17 Oct 25  2018 python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I naively assume Colab would be able to see my local hard drive. This may be possible - I am not sure - but an easy work round is to copy the code to Google drive, which Colab can see fine, e.g.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

COLAB_PATH="/content/drive/My\ Drive/afolder"

! gcloud ai-platform local train \
  --package-path COLAB_PATH \
  --module-name trainer.task \
  --job-dir local-training-output
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you dont have `python3` under `/usr/bin/` directory.

Can you run `which python3` and provide the output?

Make sure you have `python3` installed and its on system path.

Comment: /usr/bin is on path.

Answer (score 0):

please run `gcloud config set ml_engine/local_python $(which python3)` 
This is assuming you have python3 in path, if not you could also do `which python` .

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing the issue, the package path doesn't seem to be the cause, and the solution is to run the command

```
gcloud config set ml_engine/local_python $(which python3)
```

from inside the virtual environment, and not the main environment. This way, the correct Python3 path will be selected (the virtual environment's one).

Comment: Could you try testing this again, in a virtual environment inside a different environment?